# Do you need to use constraints when actually building the tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add constraints while creating a table. Is it necessary and what is the format?

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER (
OrderNumber Int   AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
CustomerID Int NOT NULL,
ItemID Char(25) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  OrderPK PRIMARY KEY(OrderNumber),
CONSTRAINT  OrderFK FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID)
    REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID),
CONSTRAINT  OrderFK FOREIGN KEY(ItemID)
    REFERENCES ITEM(ItemID)
);
```

Comment: What's your question here actually?

Comment: No, tables can be created without constraints if you don't need them.

Comment: you can add constraints later, assuming it won't cause data conflicts

Comment: A wise man would put it all together with constraints prior to loading up your data.

Comment: ok, I am getting syntax errors trying to add this code to my DB

Comment: so what is proper format to add a constraint?

Comment: yes, as well as you are free to shoot yourself in the foot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using constraints as part of the table creation is a wise idea before you add data and have problems later trying to add such constraints. Constraints added after the fact would need to occur via `ALTER TABLE` usage.

The problem with `ALTER TABLE` later is that the data is often likely not to be in such shape as to honor the referential integrity you wish. Thus those constraints cannot be added until the data is cleansed.

Here is an example of two tables to set up FK's:

I type in:

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
(   `userId` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `accounts`
(   `acctId` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `userId` INT NOT NULL,
    `acctType` CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `c_acct_2_user` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users`(`userId`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The server interprets it as:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `acctId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `acctType` char(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`acctId`),
  KEY `c_acct_2_user` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `c_acct_2_user` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The line above that states

```
KEY `c_acct_2_user` (`userId`),
```

is the server creating a helper key from the *referencing* to the *referenced*. Often those helper keys are not needed to be made for you depending on what other keys you have available in your table.

Please see the MySQL Manual Page entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

### Edit1

To help OP in request in comments:

```
CREATE SCHEMA testMonday07;
USE testMonday07;

CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMER`
(   `CustomerID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    -- other columns etc
);
CREATE TABLE `ITEM`
(   `ItemID` CHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY
    -- other columns etc
);
CREATE TABLE `ORDER` 
(   -- literally your table name. Awful name for a table as it is a Reserved Word
    `OrderNumber` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `CustomerID` INT NOT NULL,
    `ItemID` CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `some_name_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER`(`CustomerID`),
    CONSTRAINT `sdome_name_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID`) REFERENCES `ITEM`(`ItemID`)
);

DROP SCHEMA testMonday07; -- clean up, poof, all gone
```

Comment: ok thanks. Could you put mine in that format as I am having a hard time trying to understand your example?

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful

Comment: You're welcome. I usually do not use back-ticks around the table and column names as I would not choose a Reserved Word for them. Please be careful there. If you are new to MySQL then the back-ticks around the aforementioned will allow you to use such words (soon to be known to you). Please see [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and avoid the ones with an (R) next to them. Yes, you can still use them with back-ticks. But if you are power typing real fast, the back-ticks get a bit annoying to me at least.